# Concatenating Text Within a "ReadMore..." Trigger

Tags: javascript, concatenation, google-tag-manager, selectors-api

I'm trying to extract text in its entirety for a product description tag in GTM (deploying structured data, yada yada). The problem I'm facing is that **half** of the text I'm trying to extract exists within a "Read More..." link on product pages.

The layout of the elements on the page after it has rendered are:

```
<p class="product-description">
"This is the first part of the description of this product! It is read, warm,"
   <span class="morecontent" display="inline"> //inline when expanded, none when clicked
     <span class="readmore-description">
        "fuzzy, and black."
     </span>
    <a class="more-link">&nsbp;Less</a> //&nsbp;Less when expanded, &nsbp;Read More.. when clicked
  </span>
 </p>
```

I've not gotten far... all I've tried so far is:

```
function() {

  var description = document.querySelector("p.product-description");

  return description;

}
```

I'd like to get "This is the first part of the description of this product! It is read, warm, fuzzy, and black." back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used a class on content called hidden. When that class exists, content is hidden, when it doesn't exist, content displays. Think of it as a switch.

```js
$('.more-link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.morecontent').toggleClass('hidden');
  if ($('.morecontent').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.more-link').html('More');  
  }
  else {
    $('.more-link').html('Less'); 
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="product-description">
"This is the first part of the description of this product! It is read, warm,"
   <span class="morecontent hidden" display="inline"> 
     <span class="readmore-description">
        "fuzzy, and black."
     </span>
  </span>
  <a href="#" class="more-link">More</a>
 </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- I think this is similar to how the page is already architected. Do you know how I could **extract** the full description (not split into two parts) with a single function? `function() {

  var description = document.querySelector("p.product-description");

  return description;

}` is what I'm using right now but of course that doesn't work. I think the script will need to concatenate somehow.

Comment: Only if you extract them separately then concatenate them into one string in the end.